# How can I prevent losing data over wifi with python sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi4, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm trying to send data from one raspberry pi (4) to another pi (0 w) (I'm including the devices because the w 0 isn't the highest powered device, it's a little slow when running the desktop, but I'm not sure if that's the issue). The transfer generally works, but every once in a while, I lose a message. I figure I can add in an extra step to make sure the message got through and request it again if not (e.g. stick each message in a while loop to compare counter numbers), but I wasn't sure if there was a better way. Some dummy code appears below to illustrate the issue.

Client (raspberry pi 4)

```
#client
import socket
import time
import pickle
import random

HOST = '192.168.1.37'
PORT = 2031
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
counter = 0
while True:
    counter += 1
    message = ['note_off', 21, counter, time.time()]
    message_2 = pickle.dumps(message)
    print(message)
    s.send(message_2)
    time.sleep(random.random() / 10)
```

Server (raspberry pi 0 w)

```
# server
import socket
import pickle
import time
import threading

HOST = '192.168.1.37'
PORT = 2031
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
global stop
stop = False

def testa():
    counter = 0
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
    print('Connected by', addr)
    try:
        while True and not stop:
            message_2 = conn.recv(1024)
            message = pickle.loads(message_2)
            if message:
                counter += 1
                print('counter = {}, message = {}'.format(counter, message))
        s.close()
    except:
        print('closing')
        s.close()


try:
    print('creating thread')
    test_thread = threading.Thread(target=testa)
    print('starting thread')
    test_thread.start()
    print('thread started')
except:
    s.close()
    stop = True
```

So in the client code, I'm running a counter and including it in part of the message, and running a duplicate counter in the other program, so we can compare. I'm printing the output to validate.

```
counter = 1, message = ['note_off', 21, 1, 1585259341.171993]
counter = 2, message = ['note_off', 21, 2, 1585259341.2157793]
...
counter = 27, message = ['note_off', 21, 27, 1585259342.608451]
counter = 28, message = ['note_off', 21, 28, 1585259342.6267097]
counter = 29, message = ['note_off', 21, 31, 1585259342.739835]
counter = 30, message = ['note_off', 21, 32, 1585259342.813044]
counter = 31, message = ['note_off', 21, 33, 1585259342.8884292]
...
counter = 230, message = ['note_off', 21, 267, 1585259354.8655927]
counter = 231, message = ['note_off', 21, 268, 1585259354.9502656]
counter = 232, message = ['note_off', 21, 269, 1585259354.999945]
```

Counter, and then the third element of `message` should match up, and they do for a while, but then messages start to get dropped.

Note: while I was composing this, I realized that I didn't set the socket options in the client code. I ran it again with that option in there, and had the same results (missing messages). Not sure if that's relevant, or if I need that bit of code in there anyway, but thought I should mention it.

**SOLUTION** As pointed out in the comments, this was a result of my misunderstanding exactly how the stream worked (I was thinking of this a stream of messages, when it's really a stream of bytes).
In my case, since I know exactly how large the objects will be that are sent over, I can set the parameter for `recv` to look for exactly the number of bytes that are sent (there are more elegant solutions, but this one works for my case).

Comment: Could it be that your `message_2 = conn.recv(1024)` eats up two messages but `pickle.loads(message_2)` returns only one of them? `socket.SOCK_STREAM` is a TCP socket and it guarantees delivery, or quits.

Comment: A stream doesn’t guarantee that any bundle of bytes you send is delivered in one recv, or that it isn’t combined with subsequent bundles. You need to A) properly delimit your messages when you send and b) track and decode that delimiting at the receiving end, and c) report when the delimiting misses something. Most likely two sends are being concatenated into one recv so the second is ignored

Comment: E.g. at the client end`random.random()` can return 0 in which case two `send()`s will be consecutive. Make your receiving end print e.g. how much data it has received and do some diagnostic when it detects that the counter has increased by more than 1. Basically It’s your code: you should learn to debug it and to code defensively.

Comment: Thank you both. I was able to figure out the solution with your help. (Solution in original post if interested)